# Read, process continuous binary file - Efficiently

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have very large binary files with no line and no field delimiters. The goal is to process these files in to tab delimited files, efficiently.

The files are structured as follows:

Each record is a fixed length, 20 bytes. Each field is a different length, three fields of length 3, 7 and 10 bytes, respectively. Each field also represents a different data type, fields 1 and 2 are int and 3 is char.

What would be the most efficient method of processing these files? I would like to keep it as simple as possible, using Bash tools, dd/od sed/awk, avoiding perl/python if possible unless the performance difference is extreme.

Below is a working attempt, it is very slow. I am new to the above tools so detailed explanations are greatly appreciated.

```
binfile="binfile.BIN"

for (( i = 0 ; i <= 20000000 ; i += 20 ))
do
    field1=$( od "${binfile}" -An --skip-bytes"$((${i}))" --read-bytes=3 --format=dI )
    field2=$( od "${binfile}" -An --skip-bytes"$((${i}+3))" --read-bytes=7 --format=dI )
    field3=$( od "${binfile}" -An --skip-bytes"$((${i}+10))" --read-bytes=10 --format=c )

    echo - ${field1}'\t'${field2}'\t'${field3} >> output.tab
done
```

Comment: and you don't have/aren't allowed to write a 5 line c-program? That would be very simple and very-very fast. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know about C, which requires a bunch of boilerplate before you can even open a file, but pretty much anything except shell would be great

Comment: When you say binary, do you mean that the first 3 bytes and the next 7 bytes represent actual integer data in their machine level representation, not ascii versions of them? Both 3 and 7 are unusual lengths for integer data (would expect 4 and 8 instead), so there must be some padding involved. Also, endianness of the data is a consideration. Any chance that you could post a short hex dump of some sample data and corresponding output?

Comment: I never work with binary files so I won't attempt to answer your question, but for any text manipulation you should use awk and GNU awk has a binary mode so I'd suggest you take a look at that, e.g. by googling or getting the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. For any text manipulation an awk script will be orders of magnitude faster than a shell loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
fold -b -w 20 | cut --output-delimiter $'\t' -b 1-3,4-10,11-20
```

If your "cut" doesn't support --output-delimiter, try "gcut" (GNU cut) or consider installing GNU coreutils.

(Please let us know how fast the different solutions that you try are :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
open my $fh, '<:raw', shift;

local $" = "\t";

while ( read $fh, my $rec, 20 ) {
    my @f = unpack 'a3 a7 a10', $rec;
    print "@f\n";
}
```

Comment: Does this unpack the first two fields into their integer equivalents, or does it just dump the data as is? Shouldn't the resultant fields be tab separated?

Comment: @mhawke: It seems that you don't understand either the question or my answer. Why are you interrogating us?

Comment: Far less magical to use `say join "\t", unpack ...`. Why on earth would you want to use `$"`?

Comment: @ikegami: Because it keeps the statement that does the stringification and `print` clean. I much prefer it to `print join("\t", @f), "\n"` but you don't have to agree. And `$"` isn't magical, but what's wrong with Perl magic anyway?

Comment: I don't consider putting 4 lines in the middle to be "clean". I consider that the very opposite. // Magical has many meanings. I'm using the very negative meaning of "cause unexpected action at a distance", the very definition of bad programming.

Comment: @ikegami: *“4 lines”*? But anyway, I disagree with you

Comment: uh, 3. Whatever. // Not with me. Action at a distance was decided to be bad long before I touched a computer. You're disagreeing with the tenets of CS.

Comment: @ikegami: You're being petty again. If you can write a useful program without action at a distance of *two statements* then I'd love to see it

Comment: @ikegami: I am seriously weary of your endless defensive and demanding comments. I've said to you before that you're no more a guy who happens to know a little Perl. Why can't you get on with the rest of us and aim to read and learn instead of this tiresome sniping?

Comment: @Borodin, Would you rather I remove the problem from your answer?

Comment: @ikegami: That's it is it? Your only options are to snipe from the comments or to edit my post? I'd rather you were less conceited and determined to have the last word, and more reflective and grateful for other people's insights into the language that you hadn't seen before

Comment: @Borodin: you're right: I didn't understand your answer - your code does tab separate the fields on ouput, so sorry about that (I don't code in perl). However, the question clearly attempts to interpret the first 2 fields as binary integers as shown by the `--format=dI` option to `od`. Your code splits the data into records and fields, but it regurgitates the data as is. That's what I was getting at in my comment. I've asked the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Reads from STDIN, outputs to STDOUT, and performs error checking:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 20;

binmode STDIN;    

while (1) {
    my $rv = read(STDIN, my $buf, BLOCK_SIZE);
    die("Error: $!\n") if !defined($rv);
    last if !$rv;
    die("Error: Insufficient data\n") if $rv != BLOCK_SIZE;
    print(join("\t", unpack('a3 a7 a10', $buf)), "\n");
}
```

But I'm quite sure you'll find that slower than reading a lot more at a time, so I'd use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 20;

binmode STDIN;    

my $buf;    
while (1) {
    my $rv = sysread(STDIN, $buf, BLOCK_SIZE*64*1024, length($buf));
    die("Error: $!\n") if !defined($rv);
    last if !$rv;

    while (length($buf) >= BLOCK_SIZE) {
       print(join("\t", unpack('a3 a7 a10', substr($buf, 0, BLOCK_SIZE, '')), "\n");
    }
}

die("Error: Insufficient data\n") if length($buf);
```

Comment: Surely you need to deal with EINTR when you are using sysread.

Comment: @chansen, Only if you have signal handlers defined. But if you do, you need to handle `EINTR` for all systems calls (`open`, `sysread`, `print`, `open`, etc.), not just `sysread`.